# i wand to sort recorder with relationship count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

in modal

```
class product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_like_products , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :product_liked_by_users , :through => :user_like_products, :source =>:user, :foreign_key => "user_id", :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_products , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_collaborated_products, :through => :user_products, :source =>:product, :foreign_key => "product_id", :class_name => "Product"
end
```

Now i have count of product which liked by user with help of this query.

```
product.product_liked_by_users.count
```

now i want something like this.

```
@products = Product.all.order_by(product.product_liked_by_users.count in DESC)
```

if is there any method for this than please help me .

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is worked for me perfectly

```
@product.to_a.sort_by!{|p| p.user.products.size}.reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
@products = Product.joins(:product_liked_by_users).group("product_liked_by_users.id").order("count(product_liked_by_users.id) DESC")
```